# Adding same servlet name to different package shows error message

Tags: java, servlets, package

I am newbie to servlet/java. I am getting the error "The servlet name already exists" when try to add same servlet name with a new package name. I was with an impression that with a different package name it is possible to add same class name. Please lead me on this.

Comment: issue in servlet name which you used in web.xml file configuration file. Every servlet must be unique name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `servlet` must be unique name for each application. When you are creating the servlet using any IDE it will ask servlet name, those name & servlet class and url pattern are configured in `web.xml` file. So in single application each & every `servlet` identified by unique name, so servlet name must be unique.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.